# Ubuntu 16.10 Intel e1000e driver cannot be compiled. Error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, gcc

The built-in e1000e driver for an Intel Gigabit Ethernet controller does not work in Ubuntu, this is a known issue, with a known solution: download the driver from the Intel website, compile it, and install the kernel module as per usual kernel module installation instructions.

I downloaded the Intel e1000e-3.3.4 driver from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux-?product=70831

<s>After untarring, I get this error when I run `make`:</s>

```
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode /bin/sh: 1: [:
-ge: unexpected operator
Makefile:181: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0.  Stop.
```

According to [someone on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/542/), I should remove `gcc` from Ubuntu's repository (`sudo apt remove gcc`), and reinstall it from it's source. That, of course, can't be done, because that would also uninstall `bbswitch-dkms build-essential dkms g++ gcc libcuda1-367 nvidia-367 nvidia-opencl-icd-367 nvidia-prime`.

I found a link to [this page about PIE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE), but it does not contain simple copy&paste instructions to enable or disable PIE, or whatever the hell needs to be done to get this network driver module compiled.

On Unix Stack Exchange I found a question that may or may not be related, and it also doesn't contain clear instructions to patch whatever needs to be patched: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320470/apply-kernel-patch-to-support-pic-mode

My `uname -a`:

```
Linux kerbol 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE 2016-12-02**

I was advised to install gcc-4.8, `rm` `gcc` from `/usr/bin` and make a new symlink. Stubborn as I am, I did this instead (which I believe is the recommended "Ubuntu Way" of doing things):

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

When I ran `make` again, I got another error. Progress!

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o] Error 1
Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

If you Google for "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’", then you will find that you don't need `gcc-4.8` but `gcc-4.9`. So I did:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 50
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

When I ran `make` again, I got yet another error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o
In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c:24:
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c: In function ‘e1000e_dump’:
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c:250:25: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
    netdev->state, netdev->trans_start, netdev->last_rx);
                         ^
./include/linux/printk.h:283:34: note: in definition of macro ‘pr_info’
  printk(KERN_INFO pr_fmt(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                  ^
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c: In function ‘e1000_xmit_frame’:
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c:6545:8: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
  netdev->trans_start = jiffies;
        ^
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o] Error 1
Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Now it's becoming interesting because I think I found something that changed starting with 4.7 kernels.
Googling for `error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’` told me that I had to change line **6545**:

```
-netdev->trans_start = jiffies;
+netif_trans_update(netdev);
```

Indeed, this removed the error at line 6545. This still leaves me with an error at line 249-250. This is the current code:

```
pr_info("%-15s %016lX %016lX %016lX\n", netdev->name,
  netdev->state, netdev->trans_start, netdev->last_rx);
```

I know I need to replace `netdev->trans_start` with something else, but I don't know what. Using `netif_trans_update(netdev)` as the 4th parameter of `pr_info` won't work because that gives me

```
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c: In function ‘e1000e_dump’:
/home/amedee/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c:249:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   pr_info("%-15s %016lX %016lX %016lX\n", netdev->name,
   ^
```

So what do I need to put there instead?

*Apparently* `pr_info` is used for logging purposes, so I thought, what if I put lines 249-250 in comments? The result was that the driver finally builds (yay!) but *it feels wrong to comment out code if you don't know what it's function is*. Especially kernel driver code.

And even with a driver that compiles, I still don't have network after I do

```
sudo rmmod e1000e
sudo modprobe e1000e
```

UPDATE: The solution for a dual boot system is to boot into Windows, go to the driver settings of the network card, and disable everything related to power management. Then boot into Linux, reboot into Linux (yes, twice!) and use the default driver provided by the kernel.

Comment: Just wait for Intel to release a compatible driver...

Comment: Meanwhile I have no network. Not an option. I am going to get to the bottom of this, dammit, and then I am going to send Intel a patch. That's how Open Source works, didn't you know? You don't beg developers to solve a bug that doesn't interest them. You solve it yourself and you send a patch or a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Googling netif_trans_update gives the following code:

```
/* legacy drivers only, netdev_start_xmit() sets txq->trans_start */
 static inline void netif_trans_update(struct net_device *dev)
 {
         struct netdev_queue *txq = netdev_get_tx_queue(dev, 0);

        if (txq->trans_start != jiffies)
                 txq->trans_start = jiffies;
 }
```

which suggests that a good way to get the trans_start back in pr_info would be to replace

```
netdev->trans_start
```

with

```
netdev_get_tx_queue(netdev,0)->trans_start.
```

but you're right, this is a log function, fixing it probably won't fix your driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 50
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

paired with [e1000e-3.3.5.3.tar.gz](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/e1000e-3.3.5.3.tar.gz):

```
tar -xzvf e1000e-3.3.5.3.tar.gz
cd e1000e-3.3.5.3/src
sudo make install
sudo rmmod e1000e;sudo modprobe e1000e
```

builds and installs perfectly fine with no modifications on Ubuntu 16.10 with kernel `4.8.0-37-generic`.

don't forget to add e1000e to /etc/modules to make it permanent:

```
sudo echo e1000e>>/etc/modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your motherboard, when using the named e1000e-3.3.5.3 source you may need to modify the netdev.c source code when using kernels version 4.4.* or 4.8.* by removing the NVM CRC check function.